# Total records in a module suitecrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

In suitecrm how can we get total number of non-deleted records in a specific module while in before save logic hook. I searched a lot but did not find any help.

Thanks

Comment: were you able to figure out this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this.

You can use the **global $db** to call the **$db->query($sql)** method to run a SQL query or you can use the Bean Factory to to get the SugarBean and use one of the list calls to get the count.

I would recommend that you read Jim Mackins book on [SuiteCRM for Developers](https://leanpub.com/suitecrmfordevelopers), as it is a really good reference book for such issues.